# Make a button inside an element clickable while the element itself is also clickable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I have a simple sidebar, that has a bunch of list items in it, and a button right next to the list item, like so:

[image]

I attached a click handler to the `<li>` element like in the code below:

```
<li className="note" onClick={()=> props.selectNote(props.note)} role="button">
    <button className="delete-note" onClick={() => console.log('Fired')}>Delete dis</button>
    <span className="updated-at">2hr</span>
    <div className="note-content">
        <h4 className="note-title">
            {title}
        </h4>
        <p className="note-preview">
            {notePreview.substr(0, 80)}...
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

But as expected, when I click the button next to it, the actual `li` gets clicked and not the button inside it. I think this is some sort of issue with how the event bubbles, and how it's a bad practice to attach `onClick` handlers to non-interactive elements (My ESLint says that).

**What I want instead**:

1. When the list item gets clicked, the attached `onClick` event fire.
2. When the button gets clicked, fire the `onClick` event on the button, and not the `<li>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hack incoming!

I solved this by adding a `name` attribute to the elements that I didn't want to trigger the main click event:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    if(e.target.name === 'deleteButton') {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }else {
        this.props.selectNote(this.props.note)
    }
}


<li className="note" onClick={this.handleClick} role="button">
    <button className="delete-note" name="deleteButton" onClick={() => console.log('Fired')}>Delete dis</button>
    <span className="updated-at">2hr</span>
    <div className="note-content">
        <h4 className="note-title">
            {title}
        </h4>
        <p className="note-preview">
            {notePreview.substr(0, 80)}...
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

You need to check which element triggered the event, and prevent it if it was the button.

Comment: It's strange, none of the solutions seem to be working, even tho the posters say they do. :c

Comment: Mine and @LivingThing solutions should both work. Might be something in your setup. Can you create a working example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) and then we can help debug?

Comment: I just tried both of the solutions, and they work perfectly, I have no idea what caused it sadly... but hey at least it's working now. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Button onClick the default click parameter event args is passed as 'event'. Use the event.stopPropagation() to stop propogate the click event back to li.

```
<li className="note" onClick={()=> props.selectNote(props.note)} role="button">
<button className="delete-note" onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation(); console.log('Fired')}>Delete dis</button>
<span className="updated-at">2hr</span>
<div className="note-content">
    <h4 className="note-title">
        {title}
    </h4>
    <p className="note-preview">
        {notePreview.substr(0, 80)}...
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to prevent further propagation of the current event (click) in [the capturing and bubbling phases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

See the example on event propagation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

Answer (score 1):

```
<li data-is-parent className="note" onClick={(e)=> e.target.getAttribute('data-is-parent') && props.selectNote(props.note)} role="button">
    <button className="delete-note" onClick={() => console.log('Foreground Fired')}>Delete dis</button>
    <span className="updated-at">2hr</span>
    <div className="note-content">
        <h4 className="note-title">
            {title}
        </h4>
        <p className="note-preview">
            {notePreview.substr(0, 80)}...
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What does `data-is-parent` do in this situation?

Comment: its an attribute and it gets checked as targetted event attribute in onClick callback function

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your li in a div
like below

```
<div>
    <li className="note" onClick={()=> props.selectNote(props.note)} role="button">
        <span className="updated-at">2hr</span>
        <div className="note-content">
            <h4 className="note-title">
                {title}
            </h4>
            <p className="note-preview">
                {notePreview.substr(0, 80)}...
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <button className="delete-note" onClick={() => console.log('Fired')}>Delete dis </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Having an onClick event handler for `button` such as

```js
onClick={(event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
      }}
```

works well.